# many open sessions in postgresql instance

Tags: postgresql

If there are many open session with idle status on postgresql instance, I read that it could slow down the “snapshot” created for each SQL statement. I don't understand the mechanism that leads to this.

Comment: If there are many idle sessions, then your application opened those connections.

Comment: Read where? And I'm guessing they where talking about `idle in transaction` per here [pg_stat-activity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW)  under *state* not a plain `idle`.